# Entering times into Calc fails

Tags: formatting, libreoffice-calc

I am a DJ and I am trying to switch from doing my playlist calculations by hand in Notepad++ to entering everything into LibreOffice calc. My goal here is to enter the length of each track and have the running time shown in the adjacent column.

I have this all set up except even when the time columns are formatted as [MM]:SS it still forces me to type in the times as MM:SS.00 ... I will never ever have to enter fractions of a second. Why on EARTH doesn't it assume the inputted data matches the format selected? If I enter 04:36 into that column it autocorrects it to 04:36:00.00 (ie four hours thirty-six minutes, not four minutes thirty-six seconds). This is completely baffling to me and I'm at a loss as to why it's doing this.

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Apparently there's no way to do this in a single cell.  Use helper columns as described at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2352.

Comment: Can you explain to me why this behaviour is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The format affects how the information is displayed, not how it is entered or stored.  Times must always be entered either as `HH:MM:SS.00` or the underlying floating point number that represents a fraction of the day, in this case `0.00319444`.

The solution is to use helper columns as described at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2352.  Method 1:

```
        Minutes Seconds Time                Time (underlying number)
        ------- ------- -----------------   ------------------------
Format  General General MM:SS               General
Formula 4       36      =B4/1440+C4/86400   =D4
Data    4       36      04:36               0.003194444444444
```

Method 2:

```
        Hours:Minutes   Minutes:Seconds     Time (underlying number)
        -------------   -----------------   ------------------------
Format  HH:MM           MM:SS               General
Formula 4:36            =B9/60              =D9
Data    04:36           04:36               0.003194444444444
```

I prefer the first method, since the `Hours:Minutes` column in the second method contains misleading data.  However the second method is shorter and may be faster to enter.